# how to pipe an observable without creating a new instance

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Lets say i have a subject that represents pages in a paginateable table:

`pageCount$`

I then pipe that into a new variable which goes of to an API to get the data for the table:

```js
const tableData$ = pageCount$.pipe(switchMap(pageCount => getTableData(pageCount)));
```

This works great, every time i emit a new page `tableData$` emits the data for that page.

Now here comes the problem and the question i wish to solve.

On my page i also wish to use that table data to display averages of what it currently contains. So i thought i could just pipe `tableData$` through a map that performs those averages.

`const averageData$ = tableData$.pipe(map(data => performAverages(data)));`

This works, but because every-time i subscribe to each variable it creates a new instance my API call happens twice. Once for the `tableData$` subscription and once for the `averageData$` subscription. I understand this behavior is by design however.

It feels like i want to use some sort of tap/fork operator but i don't think such an operator exists.

Is it even possible to perform these tasks whilst only making the api call once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `share` operator to achieve this.

First create the observable that calls the API, and pipe it with `share`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share.

Then the resulting observable can be subscribed twice, both subscription will receive the same results, without the shared observable being called twice ('multicasting').

That should give you something along the lines of :

```
const tableData$ = pageCount$.pipe(
    switchMap(pageCount => getTableData(pageCount)),
    tap(_ => console.log('API called')),
    share()
);

// subscribe to tabledata$ twice

tableData$.subscribe(_ => console.log('get and use data once'));
tableData$.subscribe(_ => console.log('get and use data a second time'));
```

(to be tested, feedback appreciated!)

Comment: Spot on thanks. Using Angular and its async pipe to subscribe for me. Should be able to use its lifecycle hooks to connect them once thats happened.

Comment: Exactly, glad to help! And you won't need to bloat one single map or subscription with unrelated code.

Comment: With `publish` you'll have to call `tableData$.connect()` for this to emit anything. I think using `share` instead of `publish` would be all you need here.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

```
const tableData$ = pageCount$.pipe(
   switchMap(pageCount => getTableData(pageCount).pipe(
      map(data => 
         const avg = performAverages(data);
         return {data, avg}
      )
   ))
);
```

This way you get an object containing both table data and its average, which is what I understand you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that would work also and would have been my fall back. However for desired architecture the two separate observables was preferable.